# C++ class naming convention for interface classes with a concrete and namespace subclasses

Tags: c++, namespaces

A convention is the letter "I" proceeding pure virtual interface classes. Often, I find that I also need a partial concrete class with some share functionality for subclasses. So,

```
class IFoo {...}
class Foo : public IFoo {...}
```

I run into naming conundrums when I want subclasses derived from Foo differentiated by namespaces. E.g.,

```
Bar::Foo
Baz::Foo
```

Because when I code

```
namespace Bar { class Foo : public Foo {} }
```

Not surprisingly, VS gives the error "a class cannot be its own base class". (Not an issue when there's no "intermediate class, because the naming is Bar::IFoo, and Baz::IFoo.) I can get around this with

```
class MyFoo : public IFoo
namespace Bar { class Foo : public MyFoo {} }
```

or

```
namespace base { class Foo : public IFoo {} }
namespace Bar { class Foo : public base::Foo {} }
```

But would prefer not to muddle naming.

I get that having classes Foo, Bar::Foo, and Baz::Foo is bad because of the obvious confusion. (E.g., adding "using Bas;" would introduce ambiguity.) Is there a naming convention or syntax that clearly relates what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Personally, I don't use `using`. If something is too long to reasonably use, I'll use a `typedef` inside the function/class or an implementation namespace. It avoids naming conflicts and I can see where a function/class came from when it is being used.

Comment: I think you should just try to find more descriptive names for the three classes, then the problem will disppear. And the `I` convention is more of a C# thing anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acknowledging your comment that having all of these same-named types is a bad idea, you can specifically refer to a type in the global namespace by prefixing it with `::`. In this case, that means you can refer to the type `Foo` from the global namespace, while in the context of a naming scope that defines its own `Foo`, by referring to the global one as `::Foo`.  So this [works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f9f9ab0fe9d88b7):

```
class IFoo {};
class Foo : public IFoo {};

namespace Bar { class Foo : public ::Foo {}; }
```